Delay Effect in Simulation Nodes
Hello i have this  simple setup with raycast node to make a laser knd of effect


i want have a delay effect in the Endpoint of the curve to make something like this :

i tried making this with simulation zone and mixing vector of current and previous frame position but that didn't quite worked well  any help would be appreciated

if you provide a blend file - i will help. But i am too lazy to rebuild that manually - sorry.

@Chris you can just type the basic logic of how this can be achieved  i can understand from that

It is not just the GN graph, but also the animation process we would like to know. From information provided, I am guessing (1) that the laser beam is aligned with the Z axis of the "emitting" object, (2) that you are rotating this emitter and (3) that you are not using a Simulation Zone. But these are just guesses...

great: use simulation zone: store the position of the current frame, use that to bend your "real" position delayed.

@StefLAncien i just keyframed the rotation of the emitter plane  then mesh to points then set position according to hit position of raycast node then just points to curve
